# python how to efficiently find subdirectories under a big directory?

Tags: python

I wonder if there is an efficient way of getting all end/leaf subdirectories of a big directory tree.

For example, find all end/leaf dirs of would be something like this in bash, suppose there are 2 levels of directories in the tree.

```
find mydir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d
```

in python, we could use `os.walk()` to do so:

```
dirs = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mydir):
    if not dirnames:
         dirs.append(dirpath)
```

However, this runs very slow when `mydir` is big and complicated.
Ideally, we should have an iterator object for retrieving such directories.

Any ideas? thanks!

UPDATE: prefer python2.7 for solutions.

Comment: python 3.5 has `os.scandir` which is faster than `os.walk`. But traversing the full path is required to get the leaves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think an iterator will do to help? Unless you're having memory issues? Quick sanity check to make sure it's not merely a limitation of your hard disk... Create a RAM disk, copy your directory structure to it, then run again that

Comment: You can pass `topdown=False` to `os.walk` and have it go bottom-up.

Comment: just updated to ask for python2.7 solutions, will check the other suggestions here soon. Thanks a lot guys!